# Sacar un string segun la posicion en qt

Tags: qt

Hola tengo el siguiente string en QT por ejemplo:
QString fórum = "new fórum"
Y necesito coger los caracteres a partir de la tercera letra.
Se que se puede con right y left pero necesito solamente desde la tercera porque la cadena a veces se hace mas grande y no me vale tomar como referencia esto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo estudiar con cierta tranquilidad la documentación de Qt, al menos aquella referente a las clases que estás usando. En este negocio es imperativo leer la documentación de aquello que estás utilizando.

`QString` dispone de la función `mid()` que cumple perfectamente tus requisitos:

```
QString cadena = "new forum";
QString subcad = cadena.mid(3);
qDebug() << subcad;
```

Un saludo.